# can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects error when trying to create multiple instances of the same class

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I'm becoming really frustrated because of this problem. I had it before and i fixed it, but it came back again when i changed something in my code. To be precise i'm trying to create multiple instances of a class when i'm pressing a button. I am using python 3.6 with tkinter. When i was first writing my class i was using a rectangle (created by using create_rectangle method) for visual representation. After my class was behaving the way i wanted it to i wanted to use a photo to apear on my canvas instead of the rectangle. As the title sugested my main error is "can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects" and before that there are a lot of errors about deepcopy. This is the full error https://pastebin.com/nAQifmnA

Before using an image this fix worked [Can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987858/cant-pickle-tkinter-tkapp-objects)

I forgot to mention, for the image i am using PhotoImage class.

This is where i try to create more instances of the class. This method is inside the actual class, maybe that's the problem? I tried different things but they are not working.

```
def newAdd():
      global And_list
      test=AND(10,10)
      And_list.append(deepcopy(test))
      And_list =listRecord()
```

Comment: You can't create multiple of the same tkinter object, you have to create them again.

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example of how to create more objects of the same kind? i don't want it to be something like instance1= myClass, instance2= myClass, instead i want to use a function to create more objects when called

Comment: `def new():`     `inst=Myclass()`    `return inst`. Then to create a new one: `inst1=new()`. (Though I don't see what difference it make with your example....

Comment: it's ok, i fixed it, the only thing i really needed  was " test=AND(10,10)", the other parts were useless and causing errors giving no actual benefits to my code, ty a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter widgets and canvas items are just thin wrappers around objects that exist in an embedded tcl interpreter. You can't use `deepcopy` or `pickle` to create multiple instances because those commands know nothing about the embedded tcl interpreter. If you need multiple instances, you must call the appropriate tkinter functions.