# EOFError: Ran out of input while trying to store turtle information

Tags: python, shelve, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a turtle display that remembers where I've moved an object. For that I'm using the shelve module. The information about the turtle location, and the `turtle.Turtle()` itself is registered within a list within a dictonary for each turtle, like this:

```
Dots = {'A': [turtle, xcor, ycor], 'B': [turtle, xcor, ycor]}
```

I then write

```
shelfFile = shelve.open('VisualData')
shelfFile['Dots'] = Dots
```

and run the code once.

I then rewrite the second line like `Dots = shelfFile['Dots']` and run it once more, which causes the error to display. I also write `shelfFile['Dots'] = Dots` at the end of the code for it to register any changes in the data.

While I understand that is most likely a very elegant solution, I've used that every time I've used the shelve module and it worked. I am at a really loss here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to do something like:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import shelve

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.goto(100, 100)

myrtle = Turtle()
myrtle.goto(-200, -200)

dots = {
    'A': [yertle, yertle.xcor(), yertle.ycor()],
    'B': [myrtle, myrtle.xcor(), myrtle.ycor()],
}

with shelve.open('VisualData') as shelfFile:
    shelfFile['Dots'] = dots
```

But when I run the above I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object
```

Which I find discussed in:

- [can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects error when trying to create multiple instances of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50568880/5771269)

And similar SO answers.  If I were trying to pickle a turtle, I might look to the `pen()` function, in combination with `position()` and `heading()`, which describes most of a turtle's essence and is easily pickled (if not JSON'd):

```
from turtle import Turtle
import shelve

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.color('green')
yertle.goto(100, 100)

myrtle = Turtle()
myrtle.color('red')
myrtle.goto(-200, -200)
myrtle.right(45)

dots = {
    'A': [yertle.pen(), yertle.position(), yertle.heading()],
    'B': [myrtle.pen(), myrtle.position(), myrtle.heading()],
}

with shelve.open('VisualData') as shelfFile:
    shelfFile['Dots'] = dots
```

We can then restore our turtles using something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import shelve

screen = Screen()

with shelve.open('VisualData') as shelfFile:
    dots = shelfFile['Dots']

    pen, position, heading = dots['A']
    yertle = Turtle()
    yertle.pen(pen)
    yertle.penup()
    yertle.setposition(position)
    yertle.setheading(heading)

    pen, position, heading = dots['B']
    myrtle = Turtle()
    myrtle.pen(pen)
    myrtle.penup()
    myrtle.setposition(position)
    myrtle.setheading(heading)

yertle.pendown()
yertle.circle(100)

myrtle.pendown()
for _ in range(4):
    myrtle.forward(100)
    myrtle.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

And we should get these new drawings starting where the turtles were located before being pickled, and in their original colors, etc.